# How to install pyodbc on Solaris Sparc. Getting error while installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyodbc, solaris

I'm getting the below error installing:

```
# python3 -m pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/0d/bb08bb16c97765244791c73e49de9fd4c24bb3ef00313aed82e5640dee5d/pyodbc-4.0.30.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-03fk7_w4/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gf6nxri2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.64bit-3.7
    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.64bit-3.7/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -m64 -O3 -mno-app-regs -ffile-prefix-map=..=. -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -D_REENTRANT -m64 -O3 -mno-app-regs -ffile-prefix-map=..=. -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.64bit-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-03fk7_w4/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gf6nxri2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-03fk7_w4/pyodbc/
root@myhost:/home/myfolder#
```

Can you please suggest how can i get `pyodbc` installed on Solaris and get rid of the `gcc error`

After installing gcc i still get the error. See below:

```
# which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Output post gcc:

```
# python3 -m pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/0d/bb08bb16c97765244791c73e49de9fd4c24bb3ef00313aed82e5640dee5d/pyodbc-4.0.30.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mem1ma1r/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-xwk1gj4o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.64bit-3.7
    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.64bit-3.7/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -m64 -O3 -mno-app-regs -ffile-prefix-map=..=. -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -D_REENTRANT -m64 -O3 -mno-app-regs -ffile-prefix-map=..=. -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.64bit-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
    In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:
    src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
       56 | #include <sql.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mem1ma1r/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-xwk1gj4o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mem1ma1r/pyodbc/
```

Please suggest !!

Comment: `gcc` needs to be installed on that machine. Contact the person responsible for maintaining it.

Comment: `pkg install gcc`

Comment: That did not help. Update the original post your suggestion. @alanc and Gord Thompson

Comment: (cc: @alanc ) - "After installing gcc i still get the error." - Read the message carefully. It is a different error. Now you need to install `unixodbc-dev` (or `unixodbc-devel`, or whatever the Solaris repository calls it).

Comment: Solaris doesn't separate -dev or -devel packages, so it would just be `pkg install unixodbc`.